# Django-parler не видит поля

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Добрый день! Использую `Django 1.11` и `django-parler 1.8`.

Вот `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from parler.models import TranslatableModel, TranslatedFields
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Article(TranslatableModel):
    """
    Example translatable model.
    """

    # The translated fields:
    translations = TranslatedFields(
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=200),
    slug = models.SlugField("Slug"),
    content = models.TextField(),

    # Make slug unique per language
    meta={
        'unique_together': (
            ('slug', 'language_code'),
        ),
    }
)

# Regular fields
published = models.BooleanField("Is published", default=False)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Article"
    verbose_name_plural = "Articles"

    def __str__(self):
        # Fetching the title just works, as all
        # attributes are proxied to the translated model.
        # Fallbacks are handled as well.
        return "{0}".format(self.title)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        # The switch_language() is needed because we use the /##/ prefix by i18n_patterns()
        # If the language is part of the URL parameters, you can pass it directly off course.
    with switch_language(self):
            return reverse('article-details', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_all_slugs(self):
        # Example illustration, how to fetch all slugs in a single query:
        return dict(self.translations.values_list('language_code', 'slug'))
```

Взял пример из github проекта django-parlers

Вот `settings.py` :

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


PARLER_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _("English")),
    ('en-us', _("US English")),
    ('it', _('Italian')),
    ('nl', _('Dutch')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
)

PARLER_LANGUAGES = {
    None: (
        {'code': 'en', },
        {'code': 'en-us',},
        {'code': 'it',},
        {'code': 'nl',},
    ),
    'default': {
        'fallback': 'en',             # defaults to PARLER_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_CODE
        'hide_untranslated': False,   # the default; let .active_translations() return fallbacks too.
    }
}
```

В `Installed apps` так же имеется установленный 'parler` 
Когда захожу в админ панель вижу следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поля не отображаются. Так же пробовал более простые примеры, вот попытка N2

`settings.py` :

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _("English")),
    ('en-us', _("US English")),
    ('it', _('Italian')),
    ('nl', _('Dutch')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
)

PARLER_LANGUAGES = {
    1: (
        {'code': 'en',},
        {'code': 'en-us',},
        {'code': 'it',},
        {'code': 'nl',},
    ),
    'default': {
        'fallback': 'en',             # defaults to PARLER_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_CODE
        'hide_untranslated': False,   # the default; let .active_translations() return fallbacks too.
    }
}

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Amsterdam'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

И `models.py` :

```
from django.db import models
from parler.models import TranslatableModel, TranslatedFields
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from django.db import models
from parler.models import TranslatableModel, TranslatedFields

class MyModel(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        title = models.CharField(_("Title"), max_length=200)
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

При входе попытке добавить что-либо в MyModels вижу вот это - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пропишите в admin.py, следующее:

```
from parler.admin import TranslatableAdmin

class ArticleAdmin(TranslatableAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```